# How to sort an array based off an array of indexes that are in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of words based off an array of indexes. Here is the array of words:

```
const animalArray = ['Wolf', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Random']
```

Here is an Array of indexes that i have been given that correlate to the order the animal array above needs to be in:

```
const indexArray = [ 3, 0, 1, 2 ]
```

So in `indexArray`, we start off with index 3. This correlates to 'Rabbit' in the `animalsArray`. 3 is at index 0 in the `indexArray` so we should should move 'Rabbit' to index 0. We should keep doing this until we reach the end of the array. Any extras should be added to the end of the array. So once the function runs, we should get the following result:

```
sortArray(animalArray, indexArray); // ['Rabbit', 'Wolf, 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Random']
```

I have figured out the first part (create the index array). However, i don't know how to get them in the correct order. How can i put the `animalsArray` in the correct order?

EDIT:

I oversimplified this and ended up not asking the question correctly.

We should actually pass 3 params to the sortArray, the third being an object that gets sorted:

```
const animalObjects = [
 { 
  name: 'the Wolf goes to the beach'
 },
 {
  name: 'the Cat climbs a tree'
 },
 {
  name: 'the Dog runs around'
 },
 {
  name: 'the Rabbit burrows'
 },
 {
  name: 'Random extra object that should be at the end'
 }
]
```

It should sort like so:

```
sortArray(animalArray, indexArray, animalObjects);

/* returns -

[
 {
  name: 'the Rabbit burrows'
 },
 { 
  name: 'the Wolf goes to the beach'
 },

 {
  name: 'the Cat climbs a tree'
 },
 {
  name: 'the Dog runs around'
 },
 {
  name: 'Random extra object that should be at the end'
 }
]

*/
```

Comment: Can you focus your question to be about the edited part only. It is confusing to read a "history" of this question. Also, in the final version, what is the role of the first argument, when you already have the third argument? Can you update your question (and just really update it to one version of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it simple.

- Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `indexArray`
- Compare the elements in both the array using [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and push the remaining element into a result array.

**Try this :**

```js
const animalObjects = [{ 
  name: 'the Wolf goes to the beach'
 }, {
  name: 'the Cat climbs a tree'
 }, {
  name: 'the Dog runs around'
 }, {
  name: 'the Rabbit burrows'
 }, {
  name: 'Random extra object that should be at the end'
}];
const indexArray = [ 3, 0, 1, 2 ];

const newArray = indexArray.map((item) => animalObjects[item]);

animalObjects.forEach((animal) => {
    if (newArray.indexOf(animal) === -1) {
    newArray.push(animal)
  }
})

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: I made some edits to the question at the bottom, any chance you could check it out?

Comment: I saw your edit, Now what is the use of `animalArray` ? we can directly sort `animalObjects` based on the `indexArray`

Comment: @Noob I updated answer as per your edit. Hope it will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sortedAnimalArray =  []

for(var i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++ {
   sortedAnimalArray[i] = animalArray[indexArray[i]]
}
```

Comment: This is close but it doesn't add the extra items at the end, like 'Random' in the example

Answer (score 2):

Map the `indexArray` to access each element at the index, then go through the animals to identify holes.

```js
const animalArray = ['Wolf', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Random'];
const indexArray = [ 3, 0, 1, 2 ];

const indicies = new Set(indexArray);
const results = indexArray
  .map(index => animalArray[index])
  .concat(
    animalArray.filter((_, index) => !indicies.has(index))
  );
console.log(results);
```

Comment: I incorrectly asked the question and made some edits to it, please could you check it again? Apologies!

Comment: Technically, we can do this without the indexArray with the new info I provided since the animalArray contains the correct order! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise .

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
const animalArray = ['Wolf', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Random']
const indexArray = [ 3, 0, 1, 2 ] 
let pushArray = []
var resolveValue = 0
 for(var i=0;i<indexArray.length;i++){
   pushArray.push(animalArray[indexArray[i]])
   resolveValue ++
 }
 console.log(pushArray)
if(resolveValue == indexArray.length){
  resolve('Promise is resolved successfully.');  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animalObjects = [
 { 
  name: 'the Wolf goes to the beach'
 },
 {
  name: 'the Cat climbs a tree'
 },
 {
  name: 'the Dog runs around'
 },
 {
  name: 'the Rabbit burrows'
 },
 {
  name: 'Random extra object that should be at the end'
 }
]

const animalArray = ['Wolf', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Random']
const indexArray = [ 3, 0, 1, 2 ]
const animalMap  = {}

for (let i = 0; i < animalArray.length; i++) {
    animalMap[animalArray[i]] = indexArray[i]
}

for (let i = 0; i < animalObjects.length; i++) {
    const sentence = animalObjects[i].name
    for (const word of sentence.split(" ")) {
        if (animalMap[word] !== undefined) {
            animalObjects[i].position = animalMap[word]
            break
        }
    }
    if (animalObjects[i].position === undefined) {
        animalObjects[i].position = indexArray.length
    }
}

animalObjects.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position)
console.log(animalObjects)
```

We create a map of animal keyword to its supposed index, `animalMap`. For each element in `animalObjects` we search for an animal keyword, if we find one we assign the corresponding index to the `animalObject`. If we don't find any, we assume it's a random object and should come at the end. Then we sort based on these indices.

Note that if there are 2 or more animal keywords in one animal object, this algorithm takes the first and ignores the rest. In addition, this algorithm is capable of sorting `animalObjects` where the are multiple elements with the same animal keyword (like 2 elements with a name property that contain `Dog`).

This can of course be written in a much more javascriptesque way, using `map`, etc. But I thought it's important to get the algorithm right and well understood first.